# Which one is a better choice interface or enum involving the case mentioned below?

Tags: java, enums

Herbert Schildt mentions while there is nothing technically wrong with the approaches,
the enumeration is a better choice.

Consider the following:

Choice 1:

//An enumeration of the possible answers.

```
enum Answers {
    NO, YES, MAYBE, LATER, SOON, NEVER
}


public class Question {
    Random rand = new Random();

  Answers ask() {
    int prob = (int) (100 * rand.nextDouble());
    if (prob < 15)
        return Answers.MAYBE; // 15%
    else if (prob < 30)
        return Answers.NO; // 15%
    else if (prob < 60)
        return Answers.YES; // 30%
    else if (prob < 75)
        return Answers.LATER; // 15%
    else if (prob < 98)
        return Answers.SOON; // 13%else
    return Answers.NEVER; // 2%
   }
 }


public class AskMe {
  static void answer(Answers result) {
    switch (result) {
    case NO:
        System.out.println("No");
        break;
    case YES:
        System.out.println("Yes");
        break;
    case MAYBE:
        System.out.println("Maybe");
        break;
    case LATER:
        System.out.println("Later");
        break;
    case SOON:
        System.out.println("Soon");
        break;
    case NEVER:
        System.out.println("Never");
        break;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Question q = new Question();
    answer(q.ask());
    answer(q.ask());
    answer(q.ask());
    answer(q.ask());
}
```

}

Choice 2:

```
public interface SharedConstants {
   int NO = 0;
   int YES = 1;
   int MAYBE = 2;
   int LATER = 3;
   int SOON = 4;
   int NEVER = 5;
}


public class Question implements SharedConstants {

    Random rand = new Random();

   int ask() {
    int prob = (int) (100 * rand.nextDouble());
    if (prob < 30)
        return NO; // 30%
    else if (prob < 60)
        return YES; // 30%
    else if (prob < 75)
        return LATER; // 15%
    else if (prob < 98)
        return SOON; // 13%
    else
        return NEVER; // 2%
  }
}

public class AskMe implements SharedConstants {

   static void answer(int result) {
    switch (result) {
    case NO:
        System.out.println("No");
        break;
    case YES:
        System.out.println("Yes");
        break;
    case MAYBE:
        System.out.println("Maybe");
        break;
    case LATER:
        System.out.println("Later");
        break;
    case SOON:
        System.out.println("Soon");
        break;
    case NEVER:
        System.out.println("Never");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Question q = new Question();
    answer(q.ask());
    answer(q.ask());
    answer(q.ask());
    answer(q.ask());
 }
}
```

Herbert Schildt gives no reason for the same.
I am confused as to why the choice regarding the enum is a better one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Misusing a generic numerical type such as `int` as an enumeration is never a bright idea. The only reason to ever consider using it in Java is performance—and when I say performance, I mean *nanoseconds*.

You lose a lot by taking the `int` approach: the `enum` is a full-blown class and can have arbitrary methods, making it easy to streamline and organize code. You also get full type safety. In fact, the advantages so many, this answer would get too long if I tried to enumerate them all.

Comment: I am unable to explain the first para.

Comment: I am unable to explain your comment :) What's troubling you?

Comment: i mean the only reason to use it is just because of performance based on nanoseconds.

Comment: Yes, that is a fact. You don't agree?

Comment: I am working on a Loan Application Banking application but was never communicated by the designers to use them, not even once. Are they seldomly used or maybe my team has not realized the power to use them.

Comment: "them"? You mean `int`s as enum?

Answer (score 2):

You can be more confident as to what all the possible values are. For example, when you did the `int` version you dropped one of the options.

You can also include encapsulate more information rather than distributing it through your code

```
enum Answers {
    NO("No", 0.30),
    YES(Yes", 0.30),
    MAYBE("Maybe", 0.15),
    LATER("Later", 0.15),
    SOON("Soon", 0.13),
    NEVER("Never", 0.02);

    private final String description;
    private final double chance;

    private Answer(String description, double chance) {
        this.description = description;
        this.chance = chance;
    }

    public String getDescription() { return description; }

    public Answers getRandom() {
        double r = Math.random();
        for(Answer a : values())
           if ((r -= a.chance) <= 0)
               return a;
        return NEVER;
    }
}
```